# last character added in textbox

Tags: java, gwt

I have created a my KeyListener for my textbox

```
txtEmail.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {

            if(event.getUnicodeCharCode() == 32 || event.getUnicodeCharCode() == 44) {
                myFunction();
                txtEmail.setText("");
                txtEmail.setFocus(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

`myFunction()` just computing some value, `event.getUnicodeCharCode() == 32` is `SPACE` and `event.getUnicodeCharCode() == 44` is `COMMA`. so when the user presses space or comma, it will go to my function.

the problem is after the function the textbox should be empty, but it is not, if the user presses space to go to the function, after it, the textbox will contain space in the beginning, and comma if the user presses comma last..

sorry for my bad English, but i hope somebody understand my problem, thank you very much, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [this manual for KeyEvents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html#keyReleased-java.awt.event.KeyEvent-)

I think you should use the keyReleased-Method, because the method will than be called after the actual event.

In the moment your method will be called before the KeyEvent is done. Thats why you get a space or a comma in the textbox.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply... I changed `addKeyPressHandler` to `addKeyUpHandler`...